# how to remove MouseListener / ActionListener on a JTextField

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener

I have the following code adding an ActionListener to a JTextField:

```
chatInput.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
    public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
       chatInputMouseClicked(evt);
    }
});
```

Now how do I remove this MouseListener using `chatInput.removeMouseListener()`, since this function needs an argument?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can consider 3 approaches:

1) Save reference to your listener before adding it so you can remove it later:

```
MouseListener ml = new MouseAdapter() {
    public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
        chatInputMouseClicked(evt);
    }
};
chatInput.addMouseListener (ml);
...
chatInput.removeMouseListener (ml);
```

---

2) You can get all certain event listeners with correspondent methods like:

```
public MouseListener[] getMouseListeners()
```

or

```
public EventListener[] getListeners(Class listenerType)
```

Here are the javadocs for the [first](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#getMouseListeners()) and [second](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#getListeners(java.lang.Class)) methods.
If you can identify among all listeners the one which you want to remove or if you want to remove all listeners this approach may help.

---

3) You can use some boolean variable which will 'turn off' your listener. But you should notice that the variable should be a field of outer class:

```
private boolean mouseListenerIsActive;

public void doSmthWithMouseListeners () {
    mouseListenerIsActive = true;

    chatInput.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent evt) {
            if (mouseListenerIsActive) {
               chatInputMouseClicked(evt);
            }
        }
    });
}

public void stopMouseListner () {
    mouseListenerIsActive = false;
}
```

---

I would prefer the third one because it gives some flexibility and if I want to turn on mouse listener again I will not need to create new object.

Comment: I usually use the first option to permanently remove a listener from a component that lives longer that the one which registered the listener (e.g. in a `dispose()` method).

To temporarily disable a listener, I have used the third option. This is mostly required to prevent recursion. E.g. when a listener that triggers on text changes leads to a change in that same text (for whatever reason), I disable the listener at the start of its listening method and enable it at the end.

Comment: I guess I have to create a MouseListener before using it. I cant remove anonymous MouseListeners.