# How to remove Focus Listener from the JFormattedTextField, in my example of the code?

Tags: java, focuslistener

I am having trouble removing focus listener after adding it to JFormattedTextField. I read about [removeFocusListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/class-use/FocusListener.html), but couldn't find examples how to use it. It seems easy enough but no matter what I try it wouldn't work.

Here's a relevant part of the code, where I add the listener, do what I need with it, and where I want to remove it:

```
private JFormattedTextField heightArea;
heightArea.addFocusListener(new FocusListener() {
    @Override
    public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {
        heightArea.setText(getHeight(widthArea));
    }

    @Override
    public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {
    }
});
// From here on I want to remove this listener.
```

I would try things like:

```
heightArea.removeFocusListener(new FocusListener() );
```

or

```
heightArea.removeFocusListener(heightArea.FocusListener() );
```

But of course it didn't work. I am not really sure what I should pass to the removeFocusListener from heightArea to remove that focus listener.

Sorry for my inexperience, hopefully you can point me towards the right direction, so I could understand what I am doing wrong.

Any help is appreciated, thank you very much.

Comment: Here's a [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2627946/how-to-remove-mouselistener-actionlistener-on-a-jtextfield). In order to successfully remove a listener, you have to pass it the same _instance_ of the listener that you originally passed to the add method. In short, store the listener you create in a variable so you can use it whenever you want.

Comment: @sbat, thank you for your reply. That makes perfect sense I will try it out as soon as I get back home. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a class MyFocusListener and declare a class level variable of the same type. Something like this

```
MyFocusListener myFocusListener = new MyFocusListener();

    class MyFocusListener implements FocusListener {

        @Override
        public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {
           // add your logic here
        }

        @Override
        public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {

        }

    }
```

Then add/remove this listener to your textfield

```
heightArea.addFocusListener(myFocusListener);
heightArea.removeFocusListener(myFocusListener);
```

Comment: thank you very much for your answer. This perfect sense, as sbat's comment, I will try doing what you both suggested once I am back home. I will let you all how it goes. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

I used `heightArea.removeFocusListener(this)` in `focusLost`, which solved my issues.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).