# Java - disable click after JLabel is pressed

Tags: java, swing, mouseevent

I want to disable click on a same jLabel again.

For example,

I have 3 JLabels = JLabel1, JLabel2, JLabel3.
If I clicked JLabel1. I want to disable to the click for JLabel1 and only JLabel2 and JLabel3 is clickable.

I tried .setEnabled(false) in mousePressed event but it's seems that I am still able to click the JLabel.

How do I disable the click after a JLabel is clicked then?

```
public class LabelListener extends MouseAdapter {
    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        JLabel label = (JLabel) e.getSource();
        for(int i = 0; i< 3; i++) {
            if(label == jLabel[i]) {
                System.out.println("You clicked on " + i);
                label.setEnabled(false);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Remove the mouse listener in the mousePressed event handler (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2627946/how-to-remove-mouselistener-actionlistener-on-a-jtextfield)

Comment: You have to [disable (remove) your mouse event listener](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2628049/3735079).

Comment: from http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#setEnabled(boolean) "Note: Disabling a lightweight component does not prevent it from receiving MouseEvents."

Comment: Instead of removing the mouse listener why not just add an additional check to the mouse listener: `if(label.isEnabled())`

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this

```
public class LabelListener extends MouseAdapter {
    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        JLabel label = (JLabel) e.getSource();
        for(int i = 0; i< 3; i++) {
            if(label == jLabel[i]) {
                if(!label.isEnabled()){ // skip if label not enabled
                    return;
                }
                System.out.println("You clicked on " + i);
                label.setEnabled(false);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Typo? Do you mean `if (! label.isEnabled() ){`

Answer (score 0):

Just add a listener to the label that disables the label, and removes itself as a listener.

```
JLabel label = new JLabel("Label");
label.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(final MouseEvent e) {
        super.mouseClicked(e);
        label.setEnabled(false);
        label.removeMouseListener(this);
    }
 });
```

Fully runnable example:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JFrame jFrame = new JFrame();

        jFrame.getContentPane().setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        for(int i = 0; i < 3; i ++) {
            JLabel label = new JLabel("Label " + i);
            jFrame.getContentPane().add(label);
            label.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void mouseClicked(final MouseEvent e) {
                    super.mouseClicked(e);
                    System.out.println("Clicked");
                    label.setEnabled(false);
                    label.removeMouseListener(this);
                }
            });
        }

        jFrame.pack();
        jFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        jFrame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```