# Removing mouse listener in netbeans

Tags: java, swing, listener, mouse

In netbeans a mouse listener is automatically created for a component.

```
private void initComponents() {
    jLabel9 = new javax.swing.JLabel();

    jLabel9.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(150, 192, 206));
    jLabel9.setOpaque(true);
    jLabel9.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(150, 150));
    jLabel9.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
        public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
            jLabel9MouseClicked(evt);
        }
        public void mouseEntered(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
            jLabel9MouseEntered(evt);
        }
        public void mouseExited(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
            jLabel9MouseExited(evt);
        }
    });
```

The problem is how do I remove this listener for the mouse clicked event through a function? I am trying to do something like this:

```
void rem(){
   jLabel9.removeMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
        public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
            jLabel9MouseClicked(evt);
        }
     });
}
```

Then I am calling this function as required by my program flow. But this doesn't work. One thing I have figured out(though I am not sure of this) is that this is not working because I am not removing the listener through the original adapter. Instead I am creating a new one and trying to remove the original listener. I have searched almost every valid link on google but none helps.

Comment: Look at this topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2627946/how-to-remove-mouselistener-actionlistener-on-a-jtextfield

Comment: @ZsoltÉbel I have already seen that. If you notice, here, a new mouse adapter is being made, used and then removed. But my situation is different. I want to remove an instance of already created mouse adapter.

Comment: If you want a brute force method, `JComponent` has a `getMouseListeners` method which will provide you with access to all the listeners attached to the component, but I would use it with care

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where is your MouseListener reference? You are using an anonymous MouseListener. You figured it out on your own that you are removing a new MouseListener in your `removeMouseListener()` method. Why? Because you cannot access your original listener any more. Create a reference for it and your problem is solved.

```
   MouseListener mListener = new MouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
        public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
            jLabel9MouseClicked(evt);
        }
        public void mouseEntered(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
            jLabel9MouseEntered(evt);
        }
        public void mouseExited(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
            jLabel9MouseExited(evt);
        }
    });



jLabel9.addMouseListener(mListener);
jLabel9.removeMouseListener(mListener);
```

**Alternative solution**, but first one is so much easier:

```
MouseListener[] mListener = jLabel9.getMouseListeners();
for (MouseListener ml : mListener) {
    jLabel9.removeMouseListener(ml);
}
```

Comment: Thanx a lot...! Though first one is similar what I found on other links. But it doesn't work. Probably because we don't have reference to the original adapter. 
But your alternate solution works just perfectly.

Comment: can you also suggest a way on how to remove a specific listener out of many others... as in I want to remove only mouseClicked event?

Comment: Listeners are interfaces, which means that they contains abstract methods. If you implement an interface you have to implement its methods. Or you have to declare your class abstract and leave it to a subclass to implement the missing methods. So you cannot remove only the mouseClicked method because your class wouldnt meet the interface contract.

Comment: A useful article to read: [Listeners vs Adapters](https://blogs.oracle.com/CoreJavaTechTips/entry/listeners_vs_adapters)

Answer (score 0):

Almost there like Zsolt Ébel said.
    class Test {

```
JLabel jLabel9 = new JLabel();
MouseAdapter adapter = new MouseAdapter() {
    public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
        jLabel9MouseClicked(evt);
    }

    public void mouseEntered(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
        jLabel9MouseEntered(evt);
    }

    public void mouseExited(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
        jLabel9MouseExited(evt);
    }
};

private void initComponents() {
    jLabel9 = new javax.swing.JLabel();

    jLabel9.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(150, 192, 206));
    jLabel9.setOpaque(true);
    jLabel9.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(150, 150));
    jLabel9.addMouseListener(adapter);
}

void rem() {
    jLabel9.removeMouseListener(adapter);
}
```