# How to remove invalidation listener

Tags: java, javafx, listener, invalidation

I am making a music application and it involves a slider at the bottom. To fix another problem I had with the listener not being active for some reason, I had to make it so the listener was added whenever an event occurred as there was nowhere else to add it. How can I remove an invalidation listener from an object to then add another one so that I don't have loads of invalidation listeners?

The listener looks something like this:

```
someMediaPlayer.currentTimeProperty().addListener(new InvalidationListener() 
            {
                public void invalidated(Observable ov) {

                    someMethod();

                }
            });
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2627946/how-to-remove-mouselistener-actionlistener-on-a-jtextfield answers your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the code you posted you will never be able to remove it as you do not store a reference. Every time the `new InvalidationListener()` is called you will get a fresh reference. Instead store that InvalidationListener object and then you can remove it.

```
InvalidationListener listener = new InvalidationListener() 
        {
            public void invalidated(Observable ov) {

                someMethod();

            }
        };
someMediaPlayer.currentTimeProperty().addListener(listener);
....
someMediaPlayer.currentTimeProperty().removeListener(listener);
```